# Client - Server responsibility with respect to client specific resource utilization

Tags: design, client-server

If I have a repository, like a Dropbox server or a File sharing server, and if a client uses this repository for storing its data, from a design perspective, whose responsibility it is to calculate how much resource has been used / occupied by the client, assuming that there are no limits set on this, and no security concerns?

One might argue that, since it is a client's repository and client's data, it is its responsibility to calculate, by iterating or other means available, and calculate the repo size, and be responsible for it.

A counter argument could be that since it is the server which provides these resources, it is in the best position to calculate how much filesystem has been in use by which client, and provide this information to specific client when asked.

Dropbox clients, like the website and the app, provide the user with this information, but I am not sure who calculates this and where? Does the client iterate through files and folders and get the number or is it calculated and maintained at the server side, possibly in a file, and the client merely reads information in this file?
Dropbox at least is an application which is not constrained by use of protocol.

File sharing protocols like FTP or SFTP, or even WebDAV, to my knowledge, do not contain means to query on folder size, rather they return sizes of individual files and one can calculate.

Comment: *`since it is a client's repository and client's data, it is its responsibility to calculate, by iterating or other means available, and calculate the repo size, and be responsible for it`*  -- the storage belongs to the server, not to the client.    The metrics you're talking about here relate to use of that storage, and not to the data.   Furthermore, it's very likely that the underlying storage technology would probably already have those metrics available (for example, a filesystem or database)

Comment: I understand that the storage belongs to the server, and it would have this metric available, but I am somewhat surprised that this information is not provided through any mainstream file sharing protocol, and it could be argued that information on available storage capacity is a reasonably decent piece of information to have, especially since it is meant for file storage. Most implementations of file sharing protocol leave it to the client to calculate this information, particularly by some means of iteration. If servers have this info, wouldn't that make sense to include in such protocols?